# Cannot execute a Selenium IDE test case for a Pop Window

Tags: ide, selenium

Hi can any one please help me with this script please.

I cannot run a test case for pop window with selenium IDE.

here is the following script i am using to run the test case.

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/car-insurance</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTitle</td>
    <td>Car Insurance | Netpig Insurance</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//img[@alt='Get an insurance quote']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectPopUpAndWait</td>
    <td>GetaCarInsurancequote</td>
    <td>30000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTitle</td>
    <td>Car Insurance | Netpig Insurance</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txt_4_3_0_Policy_CoverDate</td>
    <td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txt_4_4_0_Policy_CoverDate</td>
    <td>05</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtRegLookup</td>
    <td>VN05XVO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>form1:imgGetVehicle</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboVehicleYearOfManufacture</td>
    <td>label=2006</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboVehicleModified</td>
    <td>label=Select</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboVehicleModified</td>
    <td>label=No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtPurchaseDateDay</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtPurchaseDateMonth</td>
    <td>02</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtPurchaseDateYear</td>
    <td>2009</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtVehicleEstimatedValue</td>
    <td>2001</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboVehicleNightLocation</td>
    <td>label=Car Park</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtOvernightPostCode</td>
    <td>wr51dh</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboVehicleCoverType</td>
    <td>label=Third Party Only</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboVolExcess</td>
    <td>label=£300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboNCBYears</td>
    <td>label=9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboNCBProtected</td>
    <td>label=No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>form1:cboNCBType</td>
    <td>label=Motorcycle</td>
</tr>
```

if any one have some solution please email mail me on dhanunjayakumar@gmial.com

Comment: I suspect someone might ask that you make your code more readable, if possible.  Also, is your email address correct?  (gmial.com)

Comment: What part of your test isn't working? Where does it stop?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This piece looks problematic it should be like

```
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name=NameOfPopupWindow</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

[error] Permission denied for http://www.netpig.co.uk to call method Location.toString on http://quotes.netpig.co.uk

Its Same Origin Policy Issue

Your popup window on http://www.netpig.co.uk is not allowed by browser to modify DOM on http://quotes.netpig.co.uk because its different domain.

Comment: Is there a solution for this while using IDE

Comment: It should not be IDE problem, Do you get any such error if you perform these actions manually ?